# printing TypedQuery in console

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to `sysout` the `TypedQuery` in eclipse console. Am trying with `.toString()` and its not working

Please find my java code below.

```
TypedQuery<PartFactor> query = entityManager
        .createQuery("from PART where partNo = :partNo ", Part.class);
    query.setParameter("partNo", partNo);
    query.setMaxResults(1);
    System.out.println("isPartNoExists -->"+query.toString());
```

Comment: Try to set the logging to "debug" level for Hibernate to see the resulting SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable logging for the the following categories:

```
org.hibernate.SQL   - set to debug to log all SQL DML statements as they are executed
org.hibernate.type - set to trace to log all JDBC parameters
```

So a log4j configuration could look like:

```
# logs the SQL statements
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug 

# Logs the JDBC parameters passed to a query
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

The first is equivalent to hibernate.show_sql=true legacy property, the second prints the bound parameters among other things.

Another solution (non hibernate based) would be to use a JDBC proxy driver like P6Spy.

In case of spring boot is being used , just config this :

aplication.yml

```
logging:
      level:
        org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
        org.hibernate.type: TRACE
```

aplication.properties

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

and nothing more.

Your log will be something like this:

```
2020-11-01 | DEBUG | o.h.SQL:127 - insert into Person (id, name, title, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```